# method for returning a single value from sqlite database as a string to be used in another class

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an android hangman game which has two classes one that holds the data base and one that has the game, what I need to do is get a single value from my database column that holds the words and return it as a string to be used in the game class. My question is how should I write the method that will be in my database class to return the value from the sqlite database and set it as a string to be sent on. I just can't seem to figure out what the sql statement or method should be I have tried many things and have got nowhere with it for days now, please please please help if you can.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a very normal usage of SQLLITE in android. I suggest you go through the tutorials. Here's one http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial. Also the notepad tutorial on the android dev website may be useful

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you're asking us is the whole sqlite schema which is way too broad to express in one answer. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JyC_xv20yE&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A) are some videos that I used to learn. Kudos to Travis/thenewboston for teaching me how to programming from scratch. After trying these, ask again if you're having Amy trouble with anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your database using getReadableDatabase().
Execute your query and get Cursor.
Call getString() in cursor with proper column index.

This is the basic steps to retrieve values from database